# How to get values from Promise in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise

I'm trying to create an array of objects from another array in React.

Here is my function

```
let filesArray = [];
filesArray = selectedDocuments.map(async (file) => {
  const imageStr = await toBase64(file);

  const parsed = imageStr.match(/^(data.*,)?(.*)$/);
  const type = parsed[1];
  const blob = parsed[2];

  return {
    content: blob,
    label: file.name,
    labelOriginal: file.name,
    dataType: type,
  }
})
```

`selectedDocuments` is the array of selected files
`toBase64` is a function I created that returns a `Promise`

The problem is that when I console `filesArray` I get this output

[image]

How can I extract the PromiseResult, and could someone explains to me what's happening and thank you.

Comment: You cannot extract the result from a promise. You must wait for the promise. The function that created the promise should be an effect, and in that effect function you should wait for the promise and then update your state with the result. If you need more help with that, please show us the full code of your component.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want to do, is to wait for all nested promises to resolve. What you're actually doing, is mapping each file to an asynchronous (promise) value. In order to get the filesArray returned values, you can simply do:

```js
let filesArray = [];
filesArray = Promise.all(selectedDocuments.map(async (file) => {
  const imageStr = await toBase64(file);

  const parsed = imageStr.match(/^(data.*,)?(.*)$/);
  const type = parsed[1];
  const blob = parsed[2];

  return {
    content: blob,
    label: file.name,
    labelOriginal: file.name,
    dataType: type,
  }
}))
```

A different way to write it inside `for...of`:

```js
let filesArray = [];

for (const document of selectedDocuments) {
  const imageStr = await toBase64(file);

  const parsed = imageStr.match(/^(data.*,)?(.*)$/);
  const type = parsed[1];
  const blob = parsed[2];

  filesArray.push({
    content: blob,
    label: file.name,
    labelOriginal: file.name,
    dataType: type,
  })
}
```

The reason I used `Promise.all` in the first example and not in the second example, is because `.map` and `for` iterate differently.

when you `.map` a value, you just run a callback with a return value. When you use the `for` loop, you iterate over it in the same scope, so each line will be  executed one after the other.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question for react.

Comment: But can you explain the fix?

Comment: @Bergi This question itself has nothing to do with react. Of course, there's a way to implement it using useEffect, but there's not enough context in the question to answer it accordingly.

Comment: @Eliya you are both right, it has nothing to do with react. I didn't include other context because it just doesn't matter I just have an input picker that set the state of selected files

Comment: @Anime if requested, I can demonstrate how it can be achieved inside a react component, but I see no reason for this specific case.

Comment: @EliyaCohen In that case I'd recommend to remove the react part from the question altogether. And then probably [close it as a duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=array%20of%20promises)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get value of a promise,then you can use async await.
or if you are using react then you can use usestate hook inside promise to get the value.
Let see with the help of example :-

let suppose we have written fetch api in another file

```
export const GetAccess= async(data)=>{
    const dta=JSON.stringify(data)
    const tknurl="http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/token/refresh/";
    let resf=await fetch(tknurl,{
        method:"post",
        headers: {
            'Content-type': 'application/json',
          },
          body:dta
        });
        let resp=await resf.json();
        let accesstoken=resp.access;
        return accesstoken;

}
```

Then we can get it's response by using another async await in app.js file

```
const Cart = () => {
    const data=useSelector((state)=>{
        return state.users
    });
    const [order,setOrder]=useState([])
    const [msg,setMsg]=useState('');
    const navigate=useNavigate();
    const all=async()=>{
        let url="http://127.0.0.1:8000/addorder/"
        let access=await GetAccess(data);
        let resp=await fetch(url,{
            method:"get",
            headers:{
                'Authorization':'Bearer '+ String(access),
            }
        });
        let res=await resp.json();
        setOrder(res);

    }
```

If you have any doubt comment it below.